# Unity "Convert To Entity" does not work (Render) with "Skinned Mesh Renderer" for Animations

Tags: unity, animation, rendering, entity-component-system, unity-dots

I'm trying to make a game with Unity's ECS and Job System.

I came across the issue where, Convert To Entity does not support Skinned Mesh Renderer. It does not render the mesh. I need it for animations.

On the bright side, Game Object Entity does render Skinned Mesh Renderer. The downside is that, it does not support Physics Shape and Physics Body. Convert To Entity does.

I am using Physics Shape and Physics Body for physics.

Would anyone mind telling me what options are open to me?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I am currently facing the same problem :/

Comment: Sadly . . no :(